# Unzipping beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I can't unzip BeautifulSoup. I'm running Windows10 on a PC and it won't recognize the tar.gz file I downloaded. The icon is empty and there is no way to extract. I see pip in my site-packages. Any help?

Comment: have you tried installing beautifulsoup via `"pip install beautifulsoup4"`?

Comment: Install `BeautifulSoup` via pip by this command - `pip install bs4`

Comment: Download and install 7zip(http://www.7-zip.org/) than extract using it

Answer (score 0):

tar.gz format is for linux operating system. The best way to install python packages is using `pip`. If possible install and uninstall your python packages only by `pip`. Because it is the most standard way for python. After installing `pip` on Windows you can install `BeautifulSoup` by below command.

```
pip install bs4
```